# Avoiding Spam - Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an Android App which sends data to a database through an API. It's basicly a reservation system for a local restaurant. I really need a way to avoid spamming the reservation system... i am a beginner in Android Dev. and i want something simple, and if you can also explain me more detailed how to use it.

Maybe a captcha, or make the "Send reservation" button available at a specified time interval or maybe a server side protection to avoid it.

Thanks you in advance !

Comment: Create the database to have a unique column, such that the same thing cant be added multiple times, or even an overwrite such that it replaces the old value if its already in the db

Comment: is this given security problem arise from the api being exposed?

Comment: The API is not exposed, i also use an access key for it. It's not a security problem i just want to avoid spamming the reservation system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this. Firstly you need to research about server-client architecture and security.

Simply;

You may use SSL certificate , send some secure header parameters in request,  encrypt some of your data.

*But first, research about architecture.*

Good luck.

Comment: I will try... any other suggestions?

Comment: Set VPN or APN for connecting the server. No one can reach without your control.